# Enable PasswordAuthentication on OpenSuse 10

Tags: ssh, opensuse

I've a virtual instance of Suse 10 running in my VMWare player, and I'm fighting against it to allow ssh password authentcation.
How can I make it working since I already have tuned the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file like that

```
#       $OpenBSD: ssh_config,v 1.20 2005/01/28 09:45:53 dtucker Exp $

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
ForwardX11 yes

ForwardX11Trusted yes

PubkeyAuthentication no
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
RSAAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication yes
HostbasedAuthentication no
Protocol 2

SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
SendEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
SendEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL
```

With ssh connection sending me the following logs

```
Incoming packet #0x5, type 51 / 0x33 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE)
  00000000  00 00 00 1e 70 75 62 6c 69 63 6b 65 79 2c 6b 65  ....publickey,ke
  00000010  79 62 6f 61 72 64 2d 69 6e 74 65 72 61 63 74 69  yboard-interacti
  00000020  76 65 00                                         ve.
Outgoing packet #0x6, type 50 / 0x32 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST)
  00000000  00 00 00 04 72 6f 6f 74 00 00 00 0e 73 73 68 2d  ....root....ssh-
  00000010  63 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74 69 6f 6e 00 00 00 14 6b 65  connection....ke
  00000020  79 62 6f 61 72 64 2d 69 6e 74 65 72 61 63 74 69  yboard-interacti
  00000030  76 65 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                    ve........
```

Telling me that it expects publickey and keyboard-interactive authentications, which I don't want to use.

Comment: Noooooo !
I was sure to edit the sshd_config file. But like both replies denotes, I edited the ssh_config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you restarted the ssh daemon?
Aren' you supposed to edit sshd_config instead?

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard-interactive is the framework in openssh that supports passwords (and possibly securid and other PAM auth methods).

Anyway, edit your sshd_config, not your ssh_config.